# sed command to replace dots

Tags: shell, sed, replace, substitution

I have a number of scripts, in which i want to scan a particular type of string, and replace dots in those strings alone. We are replacing our locator strategy from map to something else, so the variables have to be changed from having dots to having underscore

In the below, I want to change

`driver.click(objectMap.getIdentifier(new.dropdown), "DropDown clicking");`

TO

`driver.click(new_dropdown, "DropDown clicking");`

So 2 things :

1. remove the text `objectMap.getIdentifier`
2. Replace the enclosed string from having dots to underscore

If I try to use `sed 's/./_/g' >>` This will replace all the dots across, I want to replace only the dots which are enclosed within `objectMap.getIdentifier`.
Tried these sed commands, but not of much use :
`sed -e 's/objectMap.getIdentifier("\(.*\).\(.*\)")/(\1_\2)/pg'`

#### Example :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

    public class TestingScript {
    public void createNewItems(String itemName){
    driver.click(objectMap.getIdentifier(new.dropdown), "DropDown clicking");
    driver.click((objectMap.getIdentifier("new.dropdown.notes.button"), "Note from template");
    driver.click((getElement(objectMap.getIdentifier("modal.default.template").replace("$Template",  "Default")), "Default", true);
    driver.click((getElementByText(templateName), templateName);
    driver.click(objectMap.getIdentifier(new.dropdown), "DropDown clicking");
    driver.click((objectMap.getIdentifier("modal.create.button"), "Create");
  } 
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify the intended output with string literals: for driver.click(`objectMap.get_identifier("foo.bar.zoo")` - the output should be `driver.click(foo_bar_zoo`) ?

Comment: yes, this is what im looking for,

Comment: I think that there is extra '(' in the "new.dropdown.notes.button" line. It does not balanced.

Comment: @user8167143 `s/./_/g` replaces **every** character by an underscore. What comes after `s/` is treated as regular expression, and `.` means _any character_. At least you should have written `s/[.]/_/g`.

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly, it's [sed](/questions/tagged/sed),it works (as long as the lines with `objectMap.getIdentifier()` don't contain `#`)

```
#!/bin/bash

sed '
/objectMap\.getIdentifier(/{
    # copy pattern-space to hold-space
      h;
    # replace pattern-space with only the contents inside objectMap.getIdentifier()
      s/^.*objectMap\.getIdentifier(\([^)]*\)).*$/\1/;
    # replace all dots with underscores
      s/\./_/g;
    # swap pattern-space with hold-space
      x;
    # Replace objectMap.getIdentifier(.*) with a "#"
      s/objectMap\.getIdentifier([^)]*)/#/;
    # Append hold-space to pattern-space (with new-line between)
      G;
    # parse out the contents we want, use "#" as key for replacement
      s/^\([^#]*\)#\(.*\)\n\(.*\)$/\1\3\2/
}' ./infile
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ sed '/objectMap\.getIdentifier(/{h;s/^.*objectMap\.getIdentifier(\([^)]*\)).*$/\1/;s/\./_/g;x;s/objectMap\.getIdentifier([^)]*)/#/;G;s/^\([^#]*\)#\(.*\)\n\(.*\)$/\1\3\2/}' ./infile
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

    public class TestingScript {
    public void createNewItems(String itemName){
    driver.click(new_dropdown, "DropDown clicking");
    driver.click(("new_dropdown_notes_button", "Note from template....");
    driver.click((getElement("modal_default_template".replace("$Template",  "Default")), "Default", true);
    driver.click((getElementByText(templateName), templateName);
    driver.click(new_dropdown, "DropDown clicking");
    driver.click(("modal_create_button", "Create");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution ! Tried this, it says "unterminated regular expression", some bracket is not closed i think! unable to figure out, as its a lot.

Comment: Does it work if you escape the `)` inside of `[^)]` so it looks like --> `[^\)]` ?

Comment: (\([^\)]*\)) I think here there are 2 open brackets but 3 close brackets

Comment: `(\(<regex>\))` Means match a literal `(` then start a capture group with `\(` perform some `<regex>`, end the capture group with `\)` then match a literal `)`.  The regex `[^)]*` means match any character that is *not* a `)` zero or more times

Comment: @user8167143 I updated my answer with something that is a bit easier to grok and added lots of comments

Answer (score 0):

As per OP input, two requested changes

- If the key for `get_identifier` is string literal `objectMap.get_identifier("foo.bar.zoo")`, the quotes should be removed, and the key should be converted to symbolic name with '_': `foo_bar_zoo`
- If the key is a variable `objectMap.getIdentifier(new.dropdown)`, should be converted to _ separated key: `new_dropdown`

Doing this with sed is tricky, as sed is line oriented. it's hard to limit the scope of the '.' replacement to a single line.  I believe Perl will do better here. Not exactly within the constraint of OP (requested sed solution).

The first '-e' define a function to translate a single token ('.' -> '_', remove quotes)
The second '-pe' apply the function to the input.

```
perl -e 'sub fix { $_ = shift ; s/"//g ; s/\./_/g ; return $_  }' -pe 's/objectMap\.getIdentifier\(("?[a-z.]+"?)\)/fix($1)/e' < a.java
```

Might be easier to create a perl script, doing the same

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict ;
sub fix { $_ = shift ; s/"//g ; s/\./_/g ; return $_  }

while ( <> ) {
    s/objectMap\.getIdentifier\(("?[a-z.]+"?)\)/fix($1)/e ;
    print ;
}
```

Output (for sample input). Noticed unbalanced parenthesis, that exists in the input data.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

    public class TestingScript {
    public void createNewItems(String itemName){
    driver.click(new_dropdown, "DropDown clicking");
    driver.click((new_dropdown_notes_button, "Note from template");
    driver.click((getElement(modal_default_template.replace("$Template",  "Default")), "Default", true);
    driver.click((getElementByText(templateName), templateName);
    driver.click(new_dropdown, "DropDown clicking");
    driver.click((modal_create_button, "Create");
  } 
}
```

Comment: Im new to perl, can you explain me what exactly is done here?
I understood this substitution portion : s/"//g, s/\./_/g. But what exactly happens here ? while ( <> ) {
    s/objectMap\.getIdentifier\(("?[a-z.]+"?)\)/fix($1)/e ;

Comment: The 'while <>' means `for every input line`. The 's/../../e' is DYNAMIC substitution (similar to sed), with the extra power that the replacement string is calculated by the function 'fix' for each match, instead of being a static replacement string.
The dynamic call to `fix` make it possible to limit the '.' to '_' replacement to the specific patterns of `getIdentifier(...), and not impacting any other '.' or literals in the line.
I believe flexible dynamic substitution is unique to Perl, other languages (Python, Javascript, awk) will need explicit coding to achieve similar result.

Comment: There's a change in my req, sorry !Wud U b able to help
1. Click(getElement(objectMap.getIdentifier("navigate.leftsidebar").replace("$Page", "Inbox")), "clicking on an element");
2. objectMap.getIdentifier("modal.newfolder.btn")
This s d expected output:
1 > Click(getElement(objectPageFactory.navigate_leftsidebar("Inbox")), "clicking on an element");
2 > objectPageFactory(modal_newfolder_btn)

Change is : 
1. there could this text that follows as -> .replace("$anything" -> This needs to be substituted with blank (its an optional text)
2. objectMap to be replaced with objectPageFactory