# How to do multiple substitution using perl scripts

Tags: perl, substitution

I have a bunch of scripts I wanted to replace some texts.

Context :  We are using selenium for UI Automation. We used to store the references to the UiElements in a map. But we are now moving to use PageFactory (a class with all the UiElements declared as a string) 
So when we used map, we had to call the UIelements as objectMap.getIdentifier("navigate.leftsidebar"). But now with PageFactory (its like instantiating a object, and the UIElements are declared as a string), I can access these UIelements objectPageFactory.navigate_leftsidebar (here navigate_leftsidebar is a String)

So I will need to go modify all my existing scripts. Is there a way I can write a script to get this replaced, than doing it manually ?
Below are the 3 scenarios that I will encounter :

1. Click(getElement(objectMap.getIdentifier("navigate.leftsidebar").replace("$Page", "Inbox")), "clicking on an element");
2. objectMap.getIdentifier("navigate.leftsidebar")
3. Click(objectMap.getIdentifier("navigate.leftsidebar"), "clicking on an element");

This is the expected output:

1. Click((objectPageFactory.navigate_leftsidebar("Inbox")), "clicking on an element");
2. objectPageFactory.navigate_leftsidebar
3. Click(objectPageFactory.navigate_leftsidebar, "clicking on an element");

Changes are :

1. "objectMap" to be renamed as "objectPageFactory"
   There could be different types of map. if objectMap , it should be replaced as objectPageFactory; if loginMap, it should be changed as loginPageFactory
2. objectMap.getIdentifier("navigate.leftsidebar") >>>> objectFactory.navigate_leftsidebar (the String literal inside the bracket is separated by underscore instead of dots
3. getElement is not needed now
4. we used to have some dynamic UiElements (navigate.leftsidebar in this case), for which we used to call String.replace, now we are writing functions which will internally do a String.format
   getElement(objectMap.getIdentifier("navigate.leftsidebar").replace("$Page", "Inbox")) >>>>> objectPageFactory.navigate_leftsidebar("Inbox")

I got a perl script from this link, which will do partial job [sed command to replace dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62186387/sed-command-to-replace-dots#comment110045875_62188058). 
I just need to add the different scenarios to this, is there a way ? the output should now have a pageFactory text too, based on which map

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict ;

sub fix { $_ = shift ; s/"//g ; s/\./_/g ; return $_  }

while ( <> ) {
    s/getElement\(objectMap\.getIdentifier\(("?[a-z.]+"?)\)/fix($1)/e ;
    s/objectMap\.getIdentifier\(("?[a-z.]+"?)\)/fix($1)/e ;
    print
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to provide the output you requested. I don't understand the language you're changing, so there might be corner cases it processes wrong. Make a backup before you change the files!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub fix {
    my ($id) = @_;
    return $id =~ s/[.]/_/gr
}

while (<>) {
    s{getElement\((object|login)Map\.getIdentifier\("([^"]*)"\)\.replace\("\$Page", "([^"]*)"\)\)}
     {"$1PageFactory." . fix($2) . qq(("$3"))}ge;

    s{(object|login)Map\.getIdentifier\("([^"]*)"\)}
     {"$1PageFactory." . fix($2)}ge;

    print;
}
```

Comment: what should I do to handle generic cases for $Page ? I replaced as .replace\("\$[^"]*", "([^"]*)"\)\)}

But this throws error for some scenarios like :

Click(getElement(objectMap.getIdentifier("fileName").replace("$Filename", folderName)), folderName); >>>>
 Click(getElement(objectPageFactory.fileName.replace("$Filename", folderName)), folderName);
 
 
 clickJavaScript(getElement(objectMap.getIdentifier("file.moreOptions.btn").replace("$File", folderName))); >>>. 
clickJavaScript(getElement(objectMapPageFactory.file_moreOptions_btn.replace("$File", folderName)));

Comment: @user8167143: What errors? The first case gets replaces exactly as you show. The second case uses `objectPageFactory` instead of `objectMapPageFactory`, because that's what 1. and 3. showed in the example. What are the rules for selecting a factory?

Comment: never mind! there was double space in some scripts, that;s why it wasn't replacing, figured it out! Thanks for the script, it works great